# On the physical meaning of functionals and the interpretation of their output numbers

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, terminology, definition, action

I am studying about functionals, and while looking for some examples of functionals in physics, I have run into [this handout](http://quantum.phys.unm.edu/523-14/ch15.pdf) .

Here are two questions of mine.

1- This handout starts as follows (the emphasis below is mine).

> A functional $G[f]$ is a map from a space of functions to a set of
> numbers. For instance, the action functional $S[q]$ for a particle in
> one dimension maps the coordinate $q(t)$, which is a function of the
> time t, into **a number—the action of the process**.

What does "the action of the process" mean here physically? Generally, is there any (ideally broad) rule of thumb to know how the interpret the number returned by a functional?

2- A functional is supposed to yields a number out of a function. But, in the same page of the handout, it says (for a function $f(x)$)

> ... if $G_{n}[f]$ is the functional $G_{n}[f] =
>  \int\mathrm{d}xf^{n}(x)$...

An indefinite integral returns a set of functions, not a number, so it is an operator. Why is it claimed that it is a functional?

Comment: You should look up "Action Principle" on wikipedia.

Comment: @mikestone: Can you clarify how this entry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle) answers any of my questions?

Comment: *What does "the action of the process" mean here physically?* It means the value $S$ — produced by a functional — described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics) In modern physics, theories such as the Standard Model of particle physics, or General Relativity, are usually described by their action functionals rather than by their equations of motion.

Comment: *Generally, is there any (ideally broad) rule of thumb to know how the interpret the number returned by a functional?* Quantum mechanics is important when $S$ is on the order of $\hbar$. Classical mechanics becomes applicable when $S$ is much much larger than $\hbar$.

Comment: @Ghoster: Let me put my question this way. Assume a classical scenario and an action defined for it. Assume that the action returns 1 for a bound $[t_{1}, t_{2}]$ and 2 for a bound $[t_{2}, t_{3}]$. How do we interpret those "1" and "2"?

Comment: In physics the action is always a dimensional quantity (Joule-seconds in SI units). It cannot be the dimensionless number 1 or 2. If it is more Joule-seconds, it is “more classical”.

Comment: In classical mechanics the value of $S$ is irrelevant. It was not until quantum mechanics came along that the proper scale for action became known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Generally, is there any (ideally broad) rule of thumb to know how the interpret the number returned by a functional?

In general - no. But there's one exception, which comes from quantum mechanics.
If your $f(x) \land G()$ are strictly linear (degree 1 polynomials), then $G(f(x)) \in \mathbb R$ represents an inner product between function and functional, which basically shows how much co-linear your functional is to the function.

**Example**.

Take $f(x)=1+2x$ and $G(x)=1-0.5x$, then you can take coefficients of polynomials and add multiplication of them as row and column vectors, such as :
$$ G(f(x)) = \left[1~2\right] \cdot \begin{align}
     \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           −0.5 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align} = 0, \tag 1$$

Zero scalar product means that linear functional and function are perpendicular to each other or shifted by $\pi/2$ radians, which can be seen by drawing functional and a function :

[image]

Degree of alignment between linear functional and function is best seen when row and column vectors are normalized, in this case scalar product can be simplified to :
$$ \vec a \cdot \vec b = \cos \theta , \tag 2$$

which then is in range $[-1, 1]$.

But if you'll remove linearity condition,- no general meaning of returned number exist.

Answer (score 4):

> What does "the action of the process" mean here physically?

The action $S$ is the integral of the Lagrangian:
$$
S[q] = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt L(q(t),\dot q(t), t)\;,
$$
where the Lagrangian is well known from classical mechanics to be defined as:
$$
L = T - U\;,
$$
where $T$ is the kinetic energy and $U$ is the potential energy.

Varying the action $S$ with respect to the path $q(t)$ and demanding that the variation is zero turns out to give you the equations of motion. This is shown in detail in many classical mechanics textbooks. For example, the textbook by Goldstein.

To put it another way, the true classical path minimizes the action.

And, by the way, just to blow your mind a little bit: It turns out that in quantum mechanics the amplitude to arrive along any path $q(t)$ (not just the classical path) is $e^{-iS[q]/\hbar}$.

That is to say, the action is pretty darn important in physics.

> Generally, is there any (ideally broad) rule of thumb to know how the interpret the number returned by a functional?

No.

> 2- A functional is supposed to yields a number out of a function. But, in the same page of the handout, it says (for a function $f(x)$)
>
> ... if $G_{n}[f]$ is the functional $G_{n}[f] =
>  \int\mathrm{d}xf^{n}(x)$...
>
> An indefinite integral returns a set of functions, not a number, so it is an operator. Why is it claimed that it is a functional?

It's a definite integral. For example, the *action* is a definite integral:
$$
S[q] = S(t_1,t_2; x_1, x_2) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt L(q(t), \dot q(t), t)\;,
$$
which can be considered a "number" since we consider $t_1$, $t_2$, $x_1$, and $x_2$ to be fixed numbers.

Of course, you could consider the action to be a function of the endpoints, but that is just semantics.

Comment: (1) You just defined the notion of action and its relation to Lagrangian here, which is not my question. I asked about what the physical meaning of the scalar output of an action is. (2) I don't understand how you take the integral of question 2 as definite. The author has clearly set no bounds for the integral. So, what do you mean by "semantics" here?

Comment: In classical physics I guess you could say it has no meaning other than to generate the equations of motion. In quantum physics its exponential gives you the amplitude to arrive along some given path.

Comment: I mean it **is** a definite integral. When I talk about "semantics" I am talking about whether or not you consider it to be a function of the endpoints or a number

Comment: BTW, questions that are about "physical meaning" tend to get closed since the "physical meaning" can be a matter of opinion... So don't stress out too much about the "physical meaning." The meaning is the use to which it is put.

Comment: Whenever the author wants to refer to a definite integral in the hand book, they have explicitly insert integral bounds, see, e.g., equations (15.1) and (15.2). So, the integral of the question is not definite.

Comment: You will have to ask the author about that.

Comment: Physical meaning is not necessarily a matter of opinion. A simple example is the meaning of entropy which is universally interpreted as a measure of order. Anyway, if I could downvote your answer, I would. You can safely delete your answer because it does not cover anything about any of my questions.

Comment: The answer is correct. The integral is definite.

Comment: @User indeed, the author has clearly not written the bounds for the integral, but just as ‘clearly’, this author is lazy in notation; and it is not uncommon for mathematicians and physicists lazy when it comes to writing… though obviously here it did more harm than good. The author clearly has in mind definite integrals as you can see by repeated assertions of ‘suitable boundary conditions to drop surface terms’, and especially page 3 of the pdf highlighted in red “vanish at the end points of the interval”.